# How is the memory allocated when I declare a pointer of a structure in C

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, struct, allocation

I want to know how the memory is allocated when I'm using a pointer to declare my structure.

```
struct car{
    int id;
    int age;
};
```

So if I'm right, for most the compilers, the structure size is 8 bytes because int(4B) x 2 = 8B.

Now the point I don't understand.

```
//1
struct car *ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct car));
//2
char buffer[4090];
struct car *ptr = buffer;
//3
struct car *ptr = malloc(1);
```

In these 3 cases the size of the `*ptr` is 8 `sizeof(*ptr)`. Why?
And how is it represented in the memory?

Comment: To me it seems like you sizeof a pointer in all `sizeof`'s, which will obviously always have the same size on the same system.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes you'r right it's 8B each time, but i don't understand how memory allocation works. I mean how it is represented.

Comment: Try `sizeof(struct car)` and after that add another int to the struct and rerun the program. also don't remove the `sizeof(*ptr)` while doing this, it should show different results.

Comment: case 2 is constraint violation (compiler must report a problem)

Answer (score 2):

`sizeof(something)` is nothing represented in memory. It is determined at compile time.

Since `ptr` is declared as a `car*`, `sizeof(*ptr)` is for the compiler the size of the `car structure`.

This does not depend on the value of ptr or where it is pointing at, even if it is null.

On the other hand, `sizeof(ptr)` (without the star) is the size of a pointer, which depends on the system (i.e. 8 Bytes on a Win 64-bit). In this case, the type of the *pointee* does not matter.

Comment: His `sizeof` is the size of a pointer, it doesn't matter what the pointer points to, so it has nothing to do with his struct. the mere point is that he asks for the size of a pointer.

Comment: @MeikVtune read this please in the OP: "In these 3 cases the size of the *ptr is 8, WHY?". I think you will then see that the answer is pertinent, especially to that big "WHY".

Comment: `sizeof(*a)` will always output the size of a pointer, which depends on the system. `sizeof(struct car)` in this example would also output 8, since an int will output 4. that still does not change that a pointer is 8. if he was to put in a 3rd int, `sizeof(struct car)` should output 16.

Comment: @MeikVtune try it with some big structure, you will see.

Comment: I did try it. `sizeof(*anything)` will always output 8, while a struct with 3 ints, where `sizeof(struct anything)` outputs 24. Go and try it yourself if you just keep saying you are right.

Comment: Can't edit my previous comment, a struct with 3 int's will output 12, not 24. My example struct was a pointer and 3 int's.

Comment: @MeikVtune `sizeof(*anything)` will certainly not always output 8, unless `anything` is a pointer to a datatype 8 bytes long. `char * anything; printf("%zu\n", sizeof(*anything));` will output `1`, for example. In any case, there's nothing that requires all pointers to be the same size.

Answer (score 0):

The type of the expression `*ptr` is struct car, which is 8 by your own reckoning.

As to why *all three cases* say the size is 8 for the `sizeof(*ptr)`: in all three cases, C thinks of your `ptr` variable as a pointer to a car struct, declared so by you. So it cannot treat those 3 different ptr variables differently, and neither will it treat *ptr differently. It does not matter whether it's a single car item (1 case), or one of many in an array (2nd case), or indeed a completely broken bit of one byte long memory which is not even full car struct (3rd case).

C trusts the programmer to make sure that whatever is pointed at is actually there.

Comment: Please try `sizeof(int)` and `sizeof(*a)` where a is anything.

Comment: I did. In the question `ptr` is not a type, but a variable. So the type of epxression `*ptr` is `car`. And if you mean by 'where a is anything' that 'a is any type' then please consider that `sizeof(*a)` is not even correct syntax. `sizeof(a*)` is and that would indeed mean a pointer type, but I don't see how that was relevant to the question.

Comment: Ok thank you all for your answers. So if I understand there is no way to check the size of the allocated memory.